# Searching a field in Ruby-on-Rails DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, textbox

I currently have a DB in Ruby on Rails, however, I have been having trouble with the documentation on how to do much other than list all of the items in DB.  I am still new to the this language as a whole, and wish I didn't need to ask for so much help, but here it goes.  My pertinent code is as follows:

`migrate/(DB name)`

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`articles_controller.rb`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all

    Article.search(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:search])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text))

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

`article.rb`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }

    def self.search(search)
    if search
        @article = Article.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
        @article = Article.all
    end
    end

end
```

`index.html.rb`

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %> 

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>


  <%= form_tag articles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
     <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
     </p>
 <% end %>

</table>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your issue is that you're trying to set controller instance variables in a class method in your model.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.search(params[:search])
  end 
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }

  def self.search(search)
    if search.present?
      Article.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      Article.all
    end
  end    
end
```

So now the class method does the search, returns the collection to the controller which assigns them to an instance variable for use in the view.

Comment: ha, you've missed the "name" ;)

Comment: True, just copied that from OP's question

Comment: now I am receiving `Parameters: {"search"=>"asd", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"` on the backend with no change on the front end

Comment: yes I did, ill look at show, but in terms of the search, on the backend I am still not seeing the correct Select when called, `Parameters: {"search"=>"asd", "utf8"=>"✓"} Article Load (0.1ms) SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"` is what I received from the backend

Answer (score 0):

You have got your search form, made sure that is a GET one. Good. When you hit search you'll notice in your development log that there's a hit to `articles#index` and the browser will show the same as before. To make the search matter edit the `index` method in the articles controller.

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all.search(params[:search])
end
```

In `Article.search` you have a `name` where you should have a `title`.

PS: You've got the `show` method a bit wrong.

Comment: thanks, ill look at show, but in terms of the search, on the backend I am still not seeing the correct `Select` when called,  `Parameters: {"search"=>"asd", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"` is what I received from the backend

Comment: Hm, might be `Article.search(params[:search])` then like j-dexx suggested. My mongoid doesn't bother too much about the `.all`.

Comment: Nope, it still sees the search but only runs `SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"`